# Different types and sizes for each row of a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write a 2D array where each row has a different datatype and a different number of cells.
The first row contains 3 `char`s, whereas the second row contains 2 `int`s.
The function "copy" should copy byte-by-byte the array `po` into the row-array `p[1]`, but the visualization shows -24 3 instead of 1000 2000 (see picture). What is the solution? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void copy(char* dest,char* source,int dim) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<dim ;i++) 
        dest[i]=source[i];
}

int main(void) {
    char **p;
    int po[]={1000,2000};

    p = (char**) calloc(2,sizeof(char*));
    p[0]= (char*) calloc(3,sizeof(char));
    p[1]= (char*) calloc(2,sizeof(int));

    p[0][0]='A';p[0][1]='B';p[0][2]='C';
    copy((char*) p[1],(char*) po,2*sizeof(int));    

    printf("%c ",p[0][0]); printf("%c ",p[0][1]); printf("%c \n",p[0][2]);
    printf("%i ",p[1][0]); printf("%i \n",p[1][1]);         

    free(p[1]);free(p[0]);free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not array of structures?

Comment: Because I have the curiosity to see if a dynamic array in C is able to do that ...

Comment: You attempt to access an `int` array through a pointer to pointer to `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the second line of `printf`:

```
printf("%d %d \n", ((int *)p[1])[0], ((int *)p[1])[1]);
```

`p[1][1]` is the second byte (`char`) in array of chars. You want to access second `int` in array of `int`s. For that reason you have to convert `p[1]` to `int *` array and then get the element. For better readability:

```
int * p_int = (int *)p[1];
printf("%d %d \n", p_int[0], p_int[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

`1000` is represented in binary as `1111101000`. Since `int` takes 2 bytes that means with 16 bits the actual representation should be `00000011 11101000` . Although it might appear so, the actual storage in the memory happens like this.

```
11101000 00000011
```

Now this is really weird, I know. But many of the machines follow [little-endian](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-15/ass15_3.html) convention, which means that

> Whenever a multibyte value is stored, the first byte of the memory stores the least significant byte of the value.

I know this is weird, but it is very helpful to follow little-endian over big-endian(which obviously means the other way round) in implementing many algorithms.

Hence clearly `11101000` means `-24` and `00000011` means `3`. And there is no discussion about the `2000` at all because you are only asking for 2 characters and then converting them to integers using `%i`.

Now, that being said, I appreciate your curiosity and experimenting nature. But if you wanted what you expect to happen, the right piece of code would be

```
printf("%i ",((int*)p[1])[0]); 
printf("%i \n",((int*)p[1])[1]);
```

And about how you wanted to have different datatypes in a single 2-D array, it is not technically possible. But as you have already guessed, you can store all addresses in a `char*`, that is true. But then like how I did above,
you will have to cast every array to its true form. For that purpose, you will have to store the datatype of every row in some other form.(Maybe in an `int` array, by putting 0 for int, 1 for char, 2 for double etc).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to write a 2D array where each row has a different datatype

That's not going to work.  *By definition* all elements of an array are the same type.  You can't have some elements be one type and some be a different type.

If `p` has type `char **`, then `p[i]` has type `char *`, and `p[i][j]` has type `char`.  In the call

```
 printf( "%i", p[1][0] );
```

it's treating `p[1][0]` as a `char` object, not an `int` object, and thus only looking at part of the value.  You *could* do something like

```
printf( "%i", *((int *)&p[1][0]) );
```

that is, treat the *address* of `p[1][0]` as the address of an `int` object and dereference it, which is ... well, pretty eye-stabby, and prone to error.

A better option would be to create an array of `union` type where each member can store either a `char` or `int` value, like so:

```
union e { char c; int i };
union e **p = malloc( 2 * sizeof *p );
p[0] = malloc( 3 * sizeof *p[0] );
p[1] = malloc( 2 * sizeof *p[1] );

p[0][0].c = 'A'; p[0][1].c = 'B'; p[0][2].c = 'C';
p[1][0].i = 1000; p[1][1].i = 2000;

printf( "%c\n", p[0][0].c );
printf( "%i\n", p[1][0].i );
```

There's no good way to specify "this entire row must store `char` values, while that entire row must store `int` values" - you'll have to enforce that rule yourself.